# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'

Tags: python, python-3.x, rospy

absolute noob when it comes to python and i am not sure how to solve this error that i am getting "*TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'*"

I'm trying to make an extra subscriber called target so i can get the coordinates of the so called target so that the "catcher" can go to target's position.
The error is on line 54 which is :  x=TurtleCatch()

```
class TurtleCatch:
    
def __init__(self, target):
    rospy.init_node('turtlecatch_initialiser', anonymous=True)
    
    self.velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/robot1/pose', Twist, queue_size=10)
    
    self.pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/robot1/pose', Pose,  self.update_pose)
    target.pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/mytarget/pose', Pose, target.update_pose)

    target.pose = Pose()
    target.rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    self.pose = Pose()
    self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)

def euclidean_distance(self, target):
    return sqrt(pow((target.pose.x - self.pose.x), 2) + pow((target.pose.y - self.pose.y), 2))

def linear_vel(self, target, constant=1.5):
    return constant * self.euclidean_distance(target.pose)
def steering_angle(self, target):
    return atan2(target.pose.y - self.pose.y, target.pose.x - self.pose.x)
def angular_vel(self, target, constant=6):
    return constant * (self.steering_angle(target.pose) - self.pose.theta)
def move2target(self, target):
    
    distance_tolerance = 0.01;
    vel_msg = Twist()
    while self.euclidean_distance(target.pose) >= float(distance_tolerance):
        #angular velocity in y axis
        vel_msg.linear.x = self.linear_vel(target.pose)
        vel_msg.linear.y = 0
        vel_msg.linear.z = 0
        # Angular velocity in the z-axis.
        vel_msg.angular.x = 0
        vel_msg.angular.y = 0
        vel_msg.angular.z = self.angular_vel(target.pose)
        self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)
        self.rate.sleep()

        vel_msg.linear.x=0
        vel_msg.angular.z=0
        self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)
        rospy.spin()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        x = TurtleCatch()
        x.move2target()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: What is target ? `def __init__(self, target):` You need to call the class constructor  (`TurtleCatch()`) with the argument target

Comment: Inside your main you're calling `TurtleCatch.__init__()`, yet your builder needs an input value as long as you've defined this function as `def __init__(self, target)`. You need to pass a target value to the `__init__` function, otherwise the turtle won't know where to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a target to `TurtleCatch` like that: `TurtleCatch(target)`.

Here you call it with no argument (`TurtleCatch()`) so the `__init__` function complains about a missing parameter.

Comment: I thought it would just get the values from the subscriber the same as self does(self.pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/robot1/pose', Pose,  self.update_pose)). Why do i need to do this for target and not for self? Or how do i get around this, considering that what i want is for target to get the values from subscriber without me having to give it an argument

Comment: The first argument of class methods (almost always called `self`) denotes the instance itself. It is always implicitly passed to the method when you call it. You can find more info [here](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-self-variable).


If you want to be able to use `TurtleCatch()` without any argument, you need to remove `target` from the `__init__` argument list, and define it directly inside the method with `target =` (or potentially with `self.target =` if you want it to be an attribute of the class.


Note that you will face the same error with the method `move2target()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize an object of the class `TurtleCatch`, it wants the parameter `target`, which is defined by the following line:

```
def __init__(self, target):
```

But when you initialize the x variable:

```
x = TurtleCatch()
```

You do not provide this target parameter.

You should include a target in the following format:

```
x = TurtleCatch(<target>)
```

(without the <>)

Comment: I thought it would just get the values from the subscriber the same as self does(self.pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/robot1/pose', Pose, self.update_pose)). Why do i need to do this for target and not for self? Or how do i get around this, considering that what i want is for target to get the values from subscriber without me having to give it an argument